# Applying Jensen's inequality to show $\sqrt[n]{y_1...y_n} \ \leq \frac{y_1+...+y_n}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

(1) Prove $$\sqrt[n]{y_1...y_n} \ \leq \frac{y_1+...+y_n}{n}$$ where $y_1, ..., y_n\in (0,\infty)$

My attempt: I was thinking of using Jensen's inequality with the convex $\phi(t)=e^t, \ X={x_1, ..., x_n},\  \mu(x_i)=\frac{1}{i}$. Am I on the right track? I'm also not sure how to proceed from this.

(2) Prove $$y_1^{\alpha_1}...y_n^{\alpha_n} \ \le \alpha_1 y_1 + ...+ \alpha_ny_n$$ where $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i = 1$

Comment: What conditions do you have on $\alpha_i$?

Comment: The sum $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i=1$$ must hold

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form.

Comment: @wtnmath Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\log$ both sides and use concavity for $\log$ that is

$$\frac {\sum \log x_i}{n}\le \log \left( {\frac{\sum x_i}{n}}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind to elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: @wtnmath by Jensen inequality for a concave function $$\frac {\sum f( x_i)}{n}\le f \left( {\frac{\sum x_i}{n}}\right)$$ and \log x is indeed concave since $$(\log x)''=-\frac1{x^2}<0$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $$y=\ln(x)$$ is strictly concave we have
$$\ln\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_ia_i\geq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i\ln(a_i)=\ln\prod_{i=1}^na_i^{\alpha_i}$$ and since $y=\ln(x)$ is strictly increasing then follows $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_ia_i\geq \prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i^{\alpha_i}$$
For the proove of the inweighted $AM-GM$ substitute $$\alpha_i=\frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: Is there a way that I can make use of inequality of (1) to prove (2)?

Comment: what do you mean with (1),(2) exactly?

Comment: As in using $\sqrt[n]{y_1...y_n} \ \leq \frac{y_1+...+y_n}{n}$ to show $$y_1^{\alpha_1}...y_n^{\alpha_n} \ \le \alpha_1 y_1 + ...+ \alpha_ny_n$$

Comment: I think that is not possible, since your last inequality is the general case